# Simplify using arrays to populate variables

Tags: arrays, vba

My "problem" is that I have set up an array that is populated from a budget matrix where the budget can fluctuate from month to month. I have a code that works fine to grab the budget from each month, but I can't help but think there must be an easier way to populate the month budget variables.

```
Sub Calculate_CarryOver_To_Date()

'Get budget for each month

Dim Expense_Row As Integer
Dim Expense_Column(12) As Integer

'Set Settings Cross Hairs To 0
Expense_Row = 0
Erase Expense_Column

'Search for Horizontal Cross Hair
Expense_Row = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="materials", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

'Error Handle Row To Set Horizontal On
If Expense_Row = 0 Then

No_Budget = True

'Set Error Message
Financial_Report.Frame2.Visible = False

Exit Sub
End If 'End Error Handle

'Search For Vertical Cross Hair
Expense_Column(10) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="January", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(11) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="February", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(12) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="March", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(1) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="April", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(2) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="May", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(3) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="June", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(4) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="July", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(5) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="August", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(6) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="September", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(7) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="October", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(8) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="November", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Expense_Column(9) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:="December", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column


'Align Cross Hairs To Get Value
Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(1)).Value
AprA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(2)).Value
MayA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(3)).Value
JunA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(4)).Value
JulA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(5)).Value
AugA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(6)).Value
SepA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(7)).Value
OctA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(8)).Value
NovA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(9)).Value
DecA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(10)).Value
JanA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(11)).Value
FebA = Budget_This_Month

Budget_This_Month = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(12)).Value
MarA = Budget_This_Month  

End Sub
```

Is there a way to itterate through `Expense_column` and populate the monthly budget variables in a quicker way?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers, the method I used in the end was:

```
MonthSelect(1) = "April"
MonthSelect(2) = "May"
MonthSelect(3) = "June"
MonthSelect(4) = "July"
MonthSelect(5) = "August"
MonthSelect(6) = "September"
MonthSelect(7) = "October"
MonthSelect(8) = "November"
MonthSelect(9) = "December"
MonthSelect(10) = "January"
MonthSelect(11) = "February"
MonthSelect(12) = "March"


For i = 1 To 12
Expense_Column(i) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:=MonthSelect(i), _
SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
Budget_Array(i) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells(Expense_Row, Expense_Column(i)).Value
'MsgBox Budget_Array(i) 'For Testing

Next i
```

I can then just call on `Budget_Array(i)` for the value. Makes my life so much easier! thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to make each poition (index) of an array relate to the month you want to use? I.e. instead of using FebA to store it, you use Arr(1)? And then Arr(3) for April?

Comment: @ckuhn203 Yeah I realised that was probably the best way to go once I had my head round it. Much quicker that way!

Comment: Liam, you should post your final solution as another answer, not as part of your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try putting it in a for loop(I am not realy well known with vba so i cant provide a legit working vba code but i tried using the knowledge at hand) and replace all the numbers 1 to 12 with i. and create a string array of the months

```
For i = 1 To 13
 Expense_Column(i) = Worksheets("Settings").Cells.Find(What:=yourarrayofmonths(i),
SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Colum
Next i
```

again make it in a vba code, im sure you understand the concept :)

Comment: Fantastic Corwin, thanks! I guess I should have thought about using a variable as the array identifier but I have had a long few weeks with this haha.

Comment: @LiamBee we all have our moments, but this is something you can nearly alwas do when you have to hit ctrl + c, ctrl + v. Its just the matter of finding the right loop. For example your budget this month could workd the same way.